# Find the value of the integral $~\int \frac{x}{x+\ln x}~ dx~$

Tags: integration

> Find the value of the integral $$\int \dfrac{x}{x+\ln x}~  dx$$

**My attempt:** Let $~y=\ln x~$, then $~dy=\dfrac{dx}{x}~$

But I got nothing

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Is this a book problem? I don't think there is an anti derivative in terms of elementary functions

Comment: Mathematica can't give a closed form.

Comment: Integrals are like human beings. The more innocent they look the more devilish they are.

Answer (score 2):

Do not expect a closed form.

What you could do is to write
$$\frac x{x + \log (x)}=\frac 1{1 + \frac{\log( x)}x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)^n$$ making that we face
$$I_n=\int \left(\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)^n\,dx$$ Let $x=e^y$
$$I_n=\int y^n e^{(1-n)y}\,dy=-y^{n+1} E_{-n}((n-1) y)$$ where appear the exponential integral function.